# another way to write this recursive method without overloading?

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

Below code is for using recursion to populate an array with odd numbers with overloading. Before turning to overloading, I have been trying to write a recursive method that does the same job without use of overloading, working with just one parameter, which would be an integer, not a primitive array; however, I could not figure out a way to not create a new array every recursion. Can anyone enlighten me with hints/pseudo-code/whatever else that would enable me to write this method without overloading? I could not drop my curiosity even though the code below worked.
Yes, I am a beginner that recently learned recursion.

```
public static int[] oddNumbers( int index ) {
    if(index<1){
        return null;
    }
    else if(index==1){
        return oddNumbers(1, new int[1]);
    }
    else{
        return oddNumbers(index, new int[index]);
    }
}
public static int[] oddNumbers(int index, int[] array){
    if(index==1){
        array[index-1]=index*2-1;
        return array;
    }
    else{
        array[index-1]=index*2-1;
        return oddNumbers(index-1, array);
    }
}
```

Edit:Thanks for all the comments. All of them are very helpful.

Comment: Why are you populating an array with odd numbers? What does that help you solve?

Comment: It did not have to be odd numbers. I was practicing recursion with arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are trying to do is simply not possible. Arrays in java are static, so you either create a full length array at the beginning and pass it down to every recursion, like you have done, or create a full length array on the base case, which would make your function require more than one argument.

On the other hand, if what you are trying to do is practice recursion, the natural data structure here would be a list, which allows you to append your "new" odd (index*2-1 in your code) to the list returned by the recursive call. You would only create a new list on the base case (index == 1) and never pass it as argument.

Answer (score 1):

I  agreed with @Elliott Frisch. But , if you really need to do this then I will suggest you to instead of overloading you can declare a single method with 3 parameter.

As example :-

```
public static int[] oddNumbers(int index,int[] array,boolean flag){
    //Check the flag by passing true/false values and call the oddNumbers methods
}
```

When you do not need the array you can pass `null`.But, you need to maintain a flag show that you can check which method should call recursive manner.

Hope it will help you.